# Python, list index not in range

Tags: python, list, loops

I am reading in a file which consists a start time for a task and a task. The next line consists of the same thing but I will need to use the start time for the next task as the end time for the previous task.

For example:

```
09:20 Introduction \n
11:00 Exercises \n
```

Output: `09:20 - 11:00 Introduction`

I read the file in as follows:

```
def open_(self):
    sched = []
    with open(self.f_Name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            sched.append(line.strip().split())
```

This strips the `'\n'` and the splits the lines up into sublists. I then want to append the start of the next list in the overall list so I tried:

```
    for i in range(len(sched)-1):
        sched[i].append(sched[i+1][0])
```

but it gives me a list index out of bounds error, but I use `len(sched)-1` so I don't see how it goes out of bounds.

> IndexError: list index out of range

I think it might have something to do with the `[0]` part of that code as maybe it doesn't consider them to be sub lists.

Comment: Yes it might have to do with the `[0]`. Why don't you print `sched[i+1]` to see if the `[0]` is the reason?

Comment: Does your file contain any empty lines? Maybe the last line? I think split on an empty line gives you an empty list, so index 0 is out of range

Comment: Yes  I  printed each value, so definitely the [0] .

Comment: The split on an empty line was exactly the problem thank you! it shows as an empty list in output

Comment: No  as I still need to access them items. Aleph solved it tho thanks alot